# How to write 2 Python decorators in parellel

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am reading about the Python decorator as described [here](https://www.thecodeship.com/patterns/guide-to-python-function-decorators/). A function func() becomes decorated if a decorator_1 is put above func() as below

```
@decorator_1
def func():
    return
```

What if I want to build two decorators decorator_1 and decorator_2 in parallel that both use func() using the syntax with @? How would I do that? I cannot just stack one on top of the other as below since that would make it a compounding decorator.

```
@decorator_2
@decorator_1
def func():
    return
```

I understand I can dispense with the @ syntax and just write

```
func1 = decorator_1(func)
func2 = decorator_2(func)
```

to achieve my goal of constructing two decorators on one function func() in parallel, but I would like to know if there are other ways to still use the @ syntax to achieve my goal.

Comment: Not really, no.

Comment: Can u give the usecase you are trying to achieve ... Not in terms of python mechanism but at a high level..

Comment: @ArunKalirajaBaskaran: I did in the last paragraph of my question. I just edited my question to make it even clearer. Please review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorator syntax

```
@deco
def f(...):
    ...
```

is short for

```
def f(...):
    ...
f = deco(f)
```

and

```
@deco2
@deco1
def f(...):
    ...
```

is short for

```
def f(...):
    ...
f = deco2(deco1(f))
```

In particular, outer decorators only receive the output of inner decorators, not the originally decorated function (or class). Also, the only name assigned is the one used for the original function definition.

If for some reason you're determined to do this through decorator syntax, the closest you could reasonably get is

```
def multidec(*decorators):
    def inner_dec(f):
        return tuple(dec(f) for dec in decorators)
    return inner_dec

@multidec(deco1, deco2)
def f(...):
    ...
```

which would result in the final `f` being a tuple `(deco1(original_f), deco2(original_f))`, where `original_f` is the function defined by the original function definition. You could then unpack the tuple:

```
f1, f2 = f
```